# Syntax error on token ")" / "(", ; expected. - Game Development

Tags: java, abstract

so we're supposed to pass in a game engine example in java, and followed this tutorial on youtube. [Game Dev 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r00P_EoZg0&list=PLA331A6709F40B79D&index=28) --- but it doesnt work on my eclipse for some reason, it also says update and draw methods are undefined of type Core.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Window;

public abstract class Core {

public static DisplayMode modes[] = {
        //new DisplayMode(1920,1080,64,0),
        //new DisplayMode(1920,1080,32,0),
        //new DisplayMode(1920,1080,24,0),
        //new DisplayMode(1920,1080,16,0),
        new DisplayMode(800,600,32,0),
        new DisplayMode(800,600,24,0),
        new DisplayMode(800,600,16,0),
        new DisplayMode(640,480,32,0),
        new DisplayMode(640,480,24,0),
        new DisplayMode(640,480,16,0),  
};

private boolean running;
protected ScreenManager s;

//stop method
public void stop(){
    running = false;
}

//call init and gameloop
public void run(){
    try{
        init();
        gameLoop();
    }finally{
        s.restoreScreen();
    }
}

//set to fullscreen
public void init(){
    s = new ScreenManager();
    DisplayMode dm = s.findFirstCompatibleMode(modes);
    s.setFullScreen(dm);

    Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
    w.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    w.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    w.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    running = true;
}

//main gameLoop
public void gameLoop(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long cumTime = startTime;

    while(running){
        long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
        cumTime += timePassed;

        update(timePassed);

        Graphics2D g = s.getGraphics();
        draw(g);
        g.dispose();
        s.update();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    //update animation
    public void update(long timePassed){
    }

    //draw to screen
    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);

}

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyTest extends Core implements KeyListener {

public static void main(String args[]){
    new KeyTest().run();
}


private String mess = "";

//init also call init from superclass
public void init(){
    super.init();
    Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
    w.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    w.addKeyListener(this);
    mess = "press ESC to exit";
}

//key pressed
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        stop();
    }else{
        mess = "Pressed: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
        e.consume();
    }
}

//key released
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    mess = "Released: " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
    e.consume();
}

//last method from interface
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    e.consume();
}

//draw
public synchronized void draw(Graphics2D g){
    Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
    g.setColor(w.getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
    g.setColor(w.getForeground());
    g.drawString(mess, 30, 30);
}

}
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of `modes[]`

Comment: can you please explain that? and where exactly

Comment: Line 19 for the first code base.

Comment: Try not to put "URGENT" in your questions since this won't really help making people pay attention to it. Unfortunately what is urgent for you is not urgent for others and so you come across as a bit rude asking for people to hurry up helping you. Most technical forums frown upon using these kind of adjective in question subjects and might even be ignored by some people just for this so I suggest you try to instead make the question as clear as you can and provide information on what have you tried and why have you tried what you did.

Comment: Please, don't write things such as _URGENT_ in questions. This site is full of people that help for passion, they are not payed to answer your question and there is no priority here. Each question has the same priority as the others. If you really need an _urgent_ answer, consult a professional.

Comment: fixed^ sorry guys. i just really need help because this is due in a few hours and it's my first time posting here.

Comment: also the trailing comma thing did not work.

Comment: Well, you would've needed to remove the comma anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `public void gameLoop()` method. It contains `public void update(long timePassed)` and `public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);`. You have to add the `}` at the end of it's implementation and declare this 2 methods out of it, like:

```
//main gameLoop
public void gameLoop(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long cumTime = startTime;

    while(running){
        long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
        cumTime += timePassed;

        update(timePassed);

        Graphics2D g = s.getGraphics();
        draw(g);
        g.dispose();
        s.update();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
} //<-here is one you've lost

//update animation
public void update(long timePassed){
}

//draw to screen
public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);
```